# Unable to connect to HateBase API

Tags: api, python-requests, token

I'm failing to connect to HateBase API. I have broken down the code here to make the debugging easier:

```
key ='blah blah'
base_url = 'https://api.hatebase.org'
url = "https://api.hatebase.org/4-4/authenticate"
payload = "api_key=" + key
response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
token = response.json()
print(token)
```

output:

```
{'datetime': '2022-03-02 18:32:13',
 'errors': {'8752': 'The version of the API is now retired; please update your queries to resume accessing the API'},
 'important': "Your use of the HateBase API acknowledges your consent with Hatebase's Terms of Use (available online at hatebase.org) and PROHIBITS REDISTRIBUTION of this data for any purpose, including but not limited to republication in any form, such as in PUBLIC CODE REPOSITORIES.",
 'query': {'api_key': 'blah blah'},
 'version': '4.4'}
```

I'm not sure if there is a problem with HateBase API itself... Alternatively, I'd be thankful if anyone knows a source that has already collected all HateBase Vocabulary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Hatebase is no longer being actively maintained, so they retired the Hatebase API. I sent them an email about it and they suggested I try Weaponized Word instead.

> "A good alternative is The Weaponized Word, a new project which is
> very similar to Hatebase: it's free for eligible academic researchers,
> and has a multilingual lexicon, an API and a built-in natural language
> parser. At this time, language coverage on The Weaponized Word is
> roughly twice the size of Hatebase's lexicon."

That was very frustrating for me as well, because I last used the API end of 2021 so I was not sure what was happening. I haven't tried the new tool yet, but I'm happy that at least they offer an alternative :)